# Is it possible to create multi-leve environment definitions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, configuration-files

Let's say I have an app that has the usual environments: development, staging, and production. 
Then let's say I have a set of tasks that I need to run in an environment where a specific set of configuration options have been overridden -- let's say the DB host -- and these scripts (and their overrides) need to run in each environment.

One solution that comes to mind is to create a whole set of environments for each of these special cases, i.e.: `dboverride-development.rb`, `dboverride-staging`, and `dboverride-production`. Each of these environments would inherit from its main environment, but then override the necessary configuration options. But this seems cumbersome and isn't at involves a lot of code replication.

Are there existing strategies or conventions for this use-case in rails (v4 specifically)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to override any specific options as shown in the [Rails guides.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

> If you have a config/database.yml but no ENV['DATABASE_URL'] then this
> file will be used to connect to your database:
>
> If you have both config/database.yml and ENV['DATABASE_URL'] set then
> Rails will merge the configuration together. To better understand this
> we must see some examples.
>
> When duplicate connection information is provided the environment
> variable will take precedence: